# Variable in Authorization Attribute .net in base Controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-authorization

In my application, I'm trying to build an authorization - privilege based authentication.
For better understanding here's how my privileges are named and stored in my database : "GET_USERS" , "GET_USER", "DELETE_USER" ...
What I want to do is to specify the privilege name in the authorization attribute from my base controller, but the problem is that the authorization attribute only allows constant parameters.

Here's my base Controller :

```
public class BaseController<T> : ControllerBase where T : class
{
    protected readonly ConcreetDataContext _context;
    protected readonly IBaseRepository<T> _repo;
    protected readonly INotificationRepository _notificationRepo;
    protected readonly IHubContext<NotificationHub> _hubContext;
    protected readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;

    public BaseController(IHubContext<NotificationHub> hubContext,
                        ConcreetDataContext context,  
                        IBaseRepository<T> repo, 
                        INotificationRepository notifRepo)
    {
        _context = context; 
        _hubContext = hubContext;
        _repo = repo;
        _dbSet = _context.Set<T>();
        _notificationRepo = notifRepo;
    }

    // GET: api/[items]
    [HttpGet]
    // HERE's THE ISSUE
    [PrivilegeAuthorize("GET_"+typeof(T).Name.toUpper()] // this is not allowed
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<T>>> Get([FromQuery] GlobalParams globalParams)
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);
        Console.WriteLine(t.Name.ToUpper());
        var classes = await PagedList<T>.CreateAsync(_repo.Get(globalParams),globalParams.PageNumber,globalParams.PageSize);
        Response.AddPagination(classes.CurrentPage, classes.PageSize, classes.TotalCount, classes.TotalPages);
        return Ok(classes); 
    }

    // GET: api/[items]/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public virtual async Task<ActionResult<T>> Get(int id)
    {
        var item = await this._repo.GetByID(id);

        if (item == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        

        return item;
    }

    // PUT: api/[items]/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Put(int id, T item)
    {
        // if (id != item.ID)
        // {
        //     return BadRequest();
        // }
        try
        {
            await this._repo.Update(item);
            // Creating the notification 
            await this._notificationRepo.CreateNotification("Update",typeof(T).ToString(),"Updated "+typeof(T).ToString()+" with ID : "+id);
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!(await Exists(id)))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }

    // POST: api/Classes
    // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
    [HttpPost]
    public async virtual Task<ActionResult<T>> Post(T item)
    {
        await this._repo.Insert(item);
        await this._notificationRepo.CreateNotification("Create",typeof(T).ToString(),"Created "+typeof(T).ToString());
        return CreatedAtAction("Get", item);
    }

    // DELETE: api/Classes/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        var item = await _dbSet.FindAsync(id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _dbSet.Remove(item);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        var notification = await this._notificationRepo.CreateNotification("Delete",typeof(T).ToString(),"Deleted "+typeof(T).ToString());
        
        // Invoking BroadCastToUserFunction 
        var useID = Request.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
        await _hubContext.Clients.User(useID).SendAsync("simo",notification);
        return NoContent();
    }

    private async Task<bool> Exists(int id)
    {
        var item = await this._repo.GetByID(id);
        if(item != null)
        return true;
        return false;
    }
    
    [HttpGet("count")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<int>> Count([FromQuery] GlobalParams globalParams)
    {
        return await this._repo.Count(globalParams);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: You can't do this, for several reasons. Can you inherit from PrivilegeAuthorize and implement the logic in there instead?

Comment: how would I do this @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: You would create a new attribute, inherited from PrivilegeAuthorize, that figures out the privilege name at runtime.

Comment: how would the new attribute figures out the privilege name at runtime ?

Comment: I thought it had a way to know what it was applied to at runtime, but now I'm not so sure. You definitely can't work out the name of that type like that at compile time, you will have to find a different way to handle that method. There's no expression that will be constant at compile time, as well as dynamic enough to adjust for various `<T>`'s. Understand that the base class is compiled once, it is not compiled for each `<T>` variant, so the compiler will have to figure out what to pass as a string there *once*, which is not what you want.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Is it a good approach to override these methods in child controllers and specifying the privilege from there ??
i.e : [PrivilegeAuthorize("GET_USERS")]
        public override async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<City>>> Get([FromQuery] GlobalParams globalParams)

Comment: That would certainly work. Not as nice as you probably hoped it would be but at least you can centralize the code in the base class and add just `base.WhatNot(...)` implementations in the derived types.

Comment: Thank you so much @LasseV.Karlsen

Answer (score 1):

As Lasse V. Karlsen pointed out in comments: "base class is compiled once, it is not compiled for each  Variant, so the compiler will have to figure out what to pass as a string there once".

So I went with the following solution for the moment :

```
[PrivilegeAuthorize("GET_USERS")]
    public override Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<City>>> Get([FromQuery] GlobalParams globalParams)
    { 
        return base.Get(globalParams);
    }
```

I should override each method where I want to apply this authorization attribute.

Comment: You can simplify this method by removing `async` and `await` from it, there's no need for the state machine rewriting here since you're not doing anything besides just calling the base method.